# redirect in spring mvc under nginx work incorrect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, nginx

Good day!

I have a little problem: My Spring MVC application is located by `http://localhost:8080/webapp/` address. I've installed nginx for redirecting requests like `somedomain.com` to my app:

```
server{
server_name somedomain.com;
access_log /var/log/app.log;

location /{
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/webapp/;
include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
}
```

proxy.conf:

```
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

In one of controller method I use redirect, like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xxx", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String xxx(ModelMap modelMap) {
  return "redirect:/yyy";
}
```

After that, browser should open `http://somedomain.com/yyy`, but it looks for `http://somedomain.com/webapp/yyy`.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I see that no one answered this but for future needs I will.

First you need to add virtual host in tomcat for your domain and map your app to it.

Next: 
 Change
http://localhost:8080/webapp/;
To

How it works :

When you add virtual host in tomcat in server.xml under engine tag 
you say to tomcat that I want you to map this domain to my webapp. So any request comes to tomcat has the domain name in the header then tomcat will forward it to the webapp

Second

In nginx.conf

Under HTTP tag you will add server tag that listen to port 80 and a specific server name

Listen 80;
server_name somedomain.com;

So the request comes to the server tag then it will map it to the location tag

location /{
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/webapp/; //this need to be change and remove the webapp context 
include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
}

Last the request will be forwarded to tomcat and there the vHost will continue the job